# Name a field ($\ne \Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$) which contains a root of $x^5+2x^3+4x^2+6$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

This question originates from Pinter's Abstract Algebra, Chapter 27, D6.

> Name a field ($\ne \Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$) which contains a root of $x^5+2x^3+4x^2+6$.

Suppose $p(x)=x^5+2x^3+4x^2+6$ is a polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$.  Let $c$ be a root of $p(x)$.  Note $p(x)$ is irreducible by Eisenstein's Criteria. The smallest field containing $\Bbb{Q}$ and $c$ is $\Bbb{Q}(c)$ which is isomorphic to the quotient field $\Bbb{Q}/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

So if $p(x)$ is a polynomial over $\Bbb{Q}$, then the answer can be either $\Bbb{Q}(c)$ or $\Bbb{Q}[x]/\langle x^5+2x^3+4x^2+6\rangle$.

Correct?

Comment: I don't know what they mean by "name a field".  Of course you can adjoin a root, maybe the real root just to specify one.  Or all the roots if you like,  but the phrasing does suggest that you should "name" a familiar field.  Of course $\overline {\mathbb Q}$ works but is that what is intended?

Comment: Does $\mathbb F_7$ with root $x=2$ work for you?

Comment: Or $\mathbb F_2$ with root $x=0$ if finite fields are allowed.

Comment: The two fields in your description surely contain the roots of that polynomial. Besides, I believe that there are many other fields that satisfies that criterion.

Comment: I thought of $\mathbb F_2$, but it's strange to have number $6$ in it

Comment: No stranger than $2$ or $4$. The polynomial is just $x^5\pmod 2$.

Answer (score 1):

How about $1$ in $\Bbb F_{13}$?